# What's the way of aligning this things properly?

Tags: html, css

I have just started learning HTML & CSS and today I wanted to create a pretty basic sign up page. It looked pretty good until the point in which I got to find out that:

1. I don't know align the `h4` asterisk that I wanted to be red and highlight the fact that that field is not optional;
2. While trying to make the input fields wider, I found out that the "I understood and accept the Terms and Conditions." checkbox created a big gap, of which I don't know to get rid of.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.header-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}


/* Style for the logo */

.navbar__home {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}


/* Style for the nav list */

.navbar__list {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding-right: 4rem;
}


/* Style for the nav links */

.navbar__link--active {
  color: orangered;
}

.signup__today {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

.signup__div form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 4%;
}

.form-example {
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.signup__button {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>My first webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="header-nav">
      <div class="navbar__home">
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar__list">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portofolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <center>
    <div class="main__containter">
      <div class="signup__div">
        <form class="form-example" action="" method="get">
          <h1 class="signup__today">Sign-up Today</h1>
          <div class="cta__signup">
            Join us today for the best webdev experience
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <h4>User:
              <h5>*</h5>
            </h4>
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input class="name__input" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <h4>Password:
              <h5>*</h5>
            </h4>
            <label for="password"></label>
            <input class="password__input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <label>
                            <input class="terms__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="terms" required />
                            I understand and accept the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>.
                          </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <input class="signup__button" type="submit" value="Sign-up" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

I wanted the `**` that I included in `h4` to go on the same line as "User:" and "Password:" `h3`s that are placed next to, and not to have such a big gap between the checkbox and the text for accepting Terms and Conditions.

Comment: you can't nest a `h5` inside a `h4` - it's invalid html and probably why you aren't seeing the results you want - either use a `span` or a `sup`

Comment: One of the most important things to do when you're new to HTML is to get used to using an [HTML validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) regularly. It will catch a lot of simple mistakes that might otherwise waste your time and cause you frustration.

Answer (score 1):

It is invalid to have a `<h5>` inside a `<h4>` and browsers will render the `<h5>` outside the `<h4>`. Use a `<span>` element instead of a `<h5>` tag for the asterisk and target the `<span>` elements and make the text red, something like:

```css
h4 span {
  color: red;
}
```

Also consider using a `<label>` tag instead of a `<h4>` so that you can associate the text to the input. This will especially help users of assistive technologies.

For the checkbox spacing, limit the CSS selector to only the *User* and *Password* fields, something like:

```css
input:is([type=text], [type=password]) {
  width: 200px;
}
```

All together:

```css
* {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.header-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}


/* Style for the logo */

.navbar__home {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}


/* Style for the nav list */

.navbar__list {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding-right: 4rem;
}


/* Style for the nav links */

.navbar__link--active {
  color: orangered;
}

.signup__today {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

.signup__div form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 4%;
}

.form-example {
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.signup__button {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

input:is([type=text], [type=password]) {
  width: 200px;
}

h4 span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>My first webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="header-nav">
      <div class="navbar__home">
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar__list">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portofolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <center>
    <div class="main__containter">
      <div class="signup__div">
        <form class="form-example" action="" method="get">
          <h1 class="signup__today">Sign-up Today</h1>
          <div class="cta__signup">
            Join us today for the best webdev experience
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <h4>User:
              <span>*</span>
            </h4>
            <label for="name"></label>
            <input class="name__input" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <h4>Password:
              <span>*</span>
            </h4>
            <label for="password"></label>
            <input class="password__input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <label>
                            <input class="terms__checkbox" type="checkbox" name="terms" required />
                            I understand and accept the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>.
                          </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <input class="signup__button" type="submit" value="Sign-up" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For point 2 with this css input `{ width: 200px; }` you override the width to all inputs therefore the checkbox will have width of 200

To get rid of this remove the style of input and add your own class.. i named it `my_input` and put the width only on that class and apply it to name and password elements:

```css
* {
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  max-width: 100%;
}

a:visited {
  color: inherit;
}

.header-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #dfdfdf;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 0 20px;
}


/* Style for the logo */

.navbar__home {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}


/* Style for the nav list */

.navbar__list {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  padding-right: 4rem;
}


/* Style for the nav links */

.navbar__link--active {
  color: orangered;
}

.signup__today {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  line-height: 5rem;
}

.signup__div form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-radius: 4%;
}

.form-example {
  height: fit-content;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin: 2rem;
}

.signup__button {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.2rem;
}

/* make your own style for input*/
.my_input {
  padding: 4px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>My first webpage</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav class="header-nav">
      <div class="navbar__home">
        <h1>Home</h1>
      </div>
      <ul class="navbar__list">
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Portofolio</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <center>
    <div class="main__containter">
      <div class="signup__div">
        <form class="form-example" action="" method="get">
          <h1 class="signup__today">Sign-up Today</h1>
          <div class="cta__signup">
            Join us today for the best webdev experience
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <h4>User:
              <h5>*</h5>
            </h4>
            <label for="name"></label>
            <!-- add my_input to customise the element -->
            <input class="name__input my_input" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <h4>Password:
              <h5>*</h5>
            </h4>
            <label for="password"></label>
            <!-- add my_input to customise the element -->
            <input class="password__input my_input" type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" required />
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <input class="" type="checkbox" name="terms" required />
            <label>I understand and accept the <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>.
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-example">
            <input class="signup__button" type="submit" value="Sign-up" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```